# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. I cant build my flutter app :'(

Tags: android, flutter, build, build.gradle

My flutter application can't be built, when I build a message appears as below

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:.
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                            3.2s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Process finished with exit code 1

Here is my code in pastebin `enter code here`https://pastebin.com/gGsF2x5Q

Answer (score 0):

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx` try changing this line of code with this  `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0`